# Formatting a string to insert a decimal point

Tags: arrays, c, string-formatting

I have an integer 4 digits wide, which I convert to a string using sprintf.
This string array is supposed to represent a decimal number XX.XX.
eg.

```
uint16_t Value;
char buff [10];
Value = 1234;
sprintf(buff,"%04d", (unsigned int)Value);
```

I wish to display this on say a LCD or UART as 12.34.
The simplest (crude ) way would be to parse and output the array , element by element,insert the decimal period and then output the remainder of the array.
Is there a more elegant method to do this ?

Edit : I guess I oversimplified it a little. The number to be printed could be anything between 00.00 and 99.99.

sprintf(buff,"%04d", (unsigned int)Value);

I assume this would pad with leading 0's when needed.
The main reason for this coding contortions is to avoid floating point operations and the usage of printf. I would be passing a string pointer to a function which will display , character by character.

Comment: You could perhaps do `printf("%u.%02u", (unsigned)Value / 100, (unsigned)Value % 100);`

Comment: @pmg, if it is always supposed to print a leading '0' even when `Value` is less than 1000, then shouldn't the format be `%02.%02u`?

Comment: Yes @JeffHolt ... or if OP wants the number right-aligned with a space the correct format would be `"%2u.%02u"`

Comment: @JeffHolt By `%02.%02u` (which is wrong), I assume you meant `%02u.%02u`.

Comment: @pmg, The casts can be avoided with a `100u`: `printf("%u.%02u", Value / 100u, Value % 100u);`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: Neither of these forms a null terminated C string. Often, the API for an LCD display offers a simpler (faster) option of writing '*n*' characters to the display.

If this is for a microcontroller and you don't want all the (bulky and perhaps *unused*) machinery of `printf()`, there's the following:

```
void cnvrt( unsigned val, char buf[5] ) {
    buf[4] = '0' + (val % 10); val /= 10; // Least Significant Digit
    buf[3] = '0' + (val % 10); val /= 10;
    buf[2] = '.'; // separator
    buf[1] = '0' + (val % 10); val /= 10;
    buf[0] = '0' + (val % 10); // MSD
}
```

If `val < 1000` or `val > 9999`, this will still work.

---

Or, perhaps you want it as a loop:

```
void cnvrt( unsigned val, char buf[5] ) {
    for( unsigned i = 5; i--; ) {
        if( i == 2 ) buf[ i-- ] = '.';
        buf[ i ] = '0' + (val % 10);
        val /= 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example 1, is similar to what  I am doing. Example 2 is a nicer implemention and I think it will work for 00.00 to 99.99.

Answer (score 3):

If you're only working with 4 digits wide integers, a simple solution could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number = 1234;
    char buffer[200];
    sprintf(buffer, "%.2f", number/100.0);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that on UNIX systems as per sprintf manual page, this might not produce dot, depending on current locale https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf

Comment: Given OP wants "XX.XX", when `number = 123`, the output with `"%.2f"` only has 3 digits.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The OP said that they are dealing with four digits wide integers. `123` is 3 digits wide.

Comment: Fair point.,,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

If you know there's always 4 digits, you can do this without doing any extra arithmetics:

```c
int main(void)
{
    int number = 2500;
    int bufsize = 64;
    char buf[bufsize];
    snprintf(buf, bufsize, "%d", number);
    printf("%c%c.%c%c\n", buf[0], buf[1], buf[2], buf[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `25.00`

Answer (score 0):

> to represent a decimal number XX.XX

A simple approach is to convert the value to floating point and then print.

```
// 0 to '0' pad as needed
// 5 for minimum text width as in XX.XX
// .2 for always 2 digits after the '.'
sprintf(buff,"%05.2f", (double)Value / 100.0);
```

If wanting to avoid floating point math, print the whole and fraction as 2 parts.

```
sprintf(buff,"%02u.%02u", Value/100u, Value%100u);  // Note the u in 100u
```

Note that `Value` is an *unsigned* type.  With *signed* types, we need to avoid a `'-'` in the fraction

```
sprintf(buff,"%02d.%02d", iValue/100, abs(iValue%100));
```

---

In all cases, a 16-bit `uint16_t` may have values outside the 1000-9999 range ("I have an integer 4 digits") and so OP needs to define desired output for outside that range.

A simple technique to insure `Value < 10000` even when we "know" that `Value` is not supposed to be 5 digit:

```
Value %= 10000u;
sprintf(...
```